# findAndGetString() in DCMTK returns null for the tag

Tags: c++, qt, dicom, dcmtk

I am developing a quick `DICOM viewer` using `DCMTK library` and I am following the example provided in [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104921/Link-third-party-libraries-DCMTK-in-Qt-projects).

The buffer from the `API` always returns null for any tag ID, eg: `DCM_PatientName`.
But the `findAndGetOFString() API` works fine but returns only the first character of the tag in `ASCII`, is this how this API should work?

Can someone let me know why the buffer is empty the former API?

Also the `DicomImage API` also the same issue.

> Snippet 1:

```
DcmFileFormat fileformat;
OFCondition status = fileformat.loadFile(test_data_file_path.toStdString().c_str());
if (status.good())
{
   OFString  patientName;
   char* name;
   if (fileformat.getDataset()->findAndGetOFString(DCM_PatientName, patientName).good())
    {
      name = new char[patientName.length()];
      strcpy(name, patientName.c_str());
    }
    else
    {
      qDebug() << "Error: cannot access Patient's Name!";
    }
 } 
 else
 {
    qDebug() << "Error: cannot read DICOM file (" << status.text() << ")";
 }
```

In the above snippet `name` has the ASCII value "50" and the actual name is "PATIENT".

> Snippet 2:

```
DcmFileFormat file_format;  
OFCondition status = file_format.loadFile(test_data_file_path.toStdString().c_str());
std::shared_ptr<DcmDataset> dataset(file_format.getDataset());
qDebug() << "\nInformation extracted from DICOM file: \n";
const char* buffer = nullptr;
DcmTagKey key = DCM_PatientName;
dataset->findAndGetString(key,buffer);
std::string tag_value = buffer;
qDebug() << "Patient name: " << tag_value.c_str();
```

In the above snippet, the buffer is null. It doesn't read the name.

**NOTE:**

> This is only a sample. I am just playing around the APIs for learning
>   purpose.

Comment: name = new char[patientName.length()]; should be name = new char[patientName.length() + 1]; to include the null terminator. Chances are that the debugger is showing just the first char in the string. Try qDebug() << name

Comment: No luck. Prints 50. I also got this warning "W: DcmMetaInfo: Group Length of Meta Information Header has incorrect value" but the .dcm file opens fine in an existing tool.

Comment: @kaviergeoffrey if the file is anonymized can you share it?

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli added the code in the below gist:                                         https://gist.github.com/jxgeoffrey/da613d0ae796a213ebc99b87c642b485

Comment: What is the return value of findAndGetString()? What is the character string "buffer" points to? Did you already check other DICOM datasets...?

Comment: @J.Riesmeier OF_ok is the return value. The API succeeds. After calling the API the buffer points to 0x0. Tried with Patient name, id and sex, all of them behaved the same. Also, is there any specific way to build the library? If so, can you tell the exact arguments for configure to get a proper build?

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey Are you sure that these data elements have a non-empty value in the DICOM dataset? What does the "dcmdump" tool show on this DICOM file? With regard to building the DCMTK you should follow the instructions in the INSTALL file, which is part of the source code package. And, of course, you should use the latest release of the DCMTK.

Comment: @J.Riesmeier yes they have values in the datasets. I used an online tool to check them. They are all present. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

The following sample method reads the patient name from a DcmDataset object:

```
std::string getPatientName(DcmDataset& dataset)
{
    // Get the tag's value in ofstring
    OFString ofstring;
    OFCondition condition = dataset.findAndGetOFString(DCM_PatientName, ofstring);
    if(condition.good())
    {
        // Tag found. Put it in a std::string and return it
        return std::string(ofstring.c_str());
    }

    // Tag not found
    return ""; // or throw if you need the tag
}
```

Comment: This code returns just "50" ASCII for letter P of PATIENT which is in name tag...

Comment: Minor comment: Converting an OFString instance into an std::string instance is not needed when the DCMTK is compiled with STL enabled since OFString is then just another name for std::string.

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey: Then I suspect that the dataset is encoded in a character set which we do not expect here. What is the attribute value of (0008,0005) Specific Character Set?

Comment: @kritzel_sw four of the files have "ISO_IR 100" one file doesn't have that attribute itself...

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey: That is weird. Is it possible for you to share the files as they are?

Comment: @kritzel_sw https://github.com/jxgeoffrey/helloworld I have attached three .dcm files that i am using...thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code with your datasets. I just replaced the output to QT console classes to std::cout. It works for me - i.e. it prints the correct patient name (e.g. "PATIENT2" for scan2.dcm). Everything seems correct, except for the fact that you apparently want to transfer the ownership for the dataset to a smart pointer.

To obtain the ownership for the DcmDataset from the DcmFileFormat, you must call getAndRemoveDataset() instead of getDataset(). However, I do not think that your issue is related that. You may want to try my modified snippet:

```
DcmFileFormat file_format;
OFCondition status = file_format.loadFile("d:\\temp\\StackOverflow\\scan2.dcm");
std::shared_ptr<DcmDataset> dataset(file_format.getAndRemoveDataset());
std::cout << "\nInformation extracted from DICOM file: \n";
const char* buffer = nullptr;
DcmTagKey key = DCM_PatientName;
dataset->findAndGetString(key, buffer);
std::string tag_value = buffer;
std::cout << "Patient name: " << tag_value.c_str();
```

It probably helps you to know that your code and the dcmtk methods you use are correct, but that does not solve your problem. Another thing I would recommend is to verify the result returned by file_format.loadFile(). Maybe there is a surprise in there.

Not sure if I can help you more, but my next step would be to verify your build environment, e.g. the options that you use for building dcmtk. Are you using CMake to build dcmtk?